# Get External HTML code

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa app I am trying to create where it needs to basically retrieve the HTML code of a specific page, for example, google.com. From there I can personally parse the HTML code. It is hosted on lambda. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda json code (javascript) has a function:

```
var urlxxx="http://www.yoursite.com/page";   
request.get(urlxxx(), function(error, response, body);
```

However, the body must be parsed. Lambda really likes JSON to be retrieved and has built in routine to get it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
```

which makes it simple to parse the data returned from the website. Other than that, you may have to write an HTML.parse(body) function.